# Express pandas operations as pipeline

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = df.loc[:, dict_lup.values()].rename(columns={v: k for k, v in dict_lup.items()})

df['cover'] = df.loc[:, 'cover'] * 100.
df['id'] = df['condition'].map(constants.dict_c) 
df['temperature'] = (df['min_t'] + df['max_t])/2.
```

Is there a way to express the code above as a pandas pipeline? I am stuck at the first step where I rename some columns in the dataframe and select a subset of the columns.

-- EDIT:
Data is here:

```
    max_t   col_a   min_t   cover   condition   pressure
0   38.02   1523106000  19.62   0.48    269.76  1006.64
1   39.02   1523196000  20.07   0.29    266.77  1008.03
2   39  1523282400  19.48   0.78    264.29  1008.29
3   39.11   1523368800  20.01   0.7 263.68  1008.29
4   38.59   1523455200  20.88   0.83    262.35  1007.36
5   39.33   1523541600  22  0.65    261.87  1006.82
6   38.96   1523628000  24.05   0.57    259.27  1006.96
7   39.09   1523714400  22.53   0.88    256.49  1007.94
```

Comment: Can yo uadd some sample data?

Comment: I try test my solution, but `dict_lup` and `constants.dict_c` is missing. Also data sample is before `df = df.loc[:, dict_lup.values()].rename(columns={v: k for k, v in dict_lup.items()})` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df = df.loc[:, dict_lup.values()].rename(columns={v: k for k, v in dict_lup.items()})
       .assign(cover = df['cover'] * 100.,
               id = df['condition'].map(constants.dict_c),
               temperature = (df['min_t'] + df['max_t'])/2.)
```

Comment: thanks @jezrael, the soln helps. I did have to call the `df.loc[:, dict_lup.values()].rename(columns={v: k for k, v in dict_lup.items()})` part separately since it did not seem to be doing column renaming when called from within a pipe